# Laravel not getting redirected properly

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

In Laravel I have a web Route

```
  Route::get('/signout', 'GlobalController@getLogout');
```

I use a logout option in my page as

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ url('signout') }}">
       <i class="icon-key font-red-thunderbird"></i> Log Out
    </a>
</li>
```

The same way I have a ajax Change password success js script as

```
function parseError(response)
{
        var res = 0;
        $.each(response, function(i, item){
                $('#'+i+'_message').html(item);
                if(item!=1)
                $('#'+i+'_message').css('display', (item!=1)?'block':'none');
                else
                res += parseInt(item);
        });
        if(res != 0 )
        {
                bootbox.alert("Password changed successfully..!");
                window.location='/signout';
        }
}
```

But the **window.location='/signout';** is not touching the function **getLogout()** but the screen is changing to the login screen.

I have written a set of functions in **getLogout** which is not executing. What could be the problem.

Comment: try this `window.location.href = "{{URL::to('/signout')}}"`

Comment: It is a JS file

Comment: i know if the script is inside the blade file , it should work fine

Comment: You could get the url from the href attribute no ? `$('mylink').attr('href')` ? 
Also, after the logout you are redirected to the login page ? It's seems quite normal as behavior  no ? If not, check you controller for the logout, maybe it's behind a check if the user is logged (middleware ? )

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<script>
// your "Imaginary javascript"
 window.location.href = '{{url("yoururl")}}';
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script>
 window.location.href = '{{route("myRoute")}}'; 
</script>
```

Comment: @VijayanandPremnath: Please follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218822/laravel-4-redirect-to-a-route-inside-javascript-code-blade-template) hope this help for you!!!